# Lista y archivos

Tags: python

Necesito crear una función que no recibe parámetros y retorna una lista de instancias de baldosas. En ella debes abrir el archivo baldosas.txt y leer la información de las baldosas.

> Debo crear una lista e ir guardando cada baldosa creada en el mismo orden en que está su información dentro del archivo de texto. Una vez creadas todas las baldosas, la función deberá retornar dicha lista de baldosas.
> La información de cada camino será entregada en una sola línea, separada por espacios.

Hasta el momento pude abrir el archivo baldosas y crear una lista con todo, pero no logro crear los caminos.

```py
def ca_minos():

    archivo = open("baldosas.txt", "r")
 
    lista = [linea.rstrip("\n") for linea in archivo]

output = ['4', '2', 'N O azul', 'E S azul', '3', 'F O rojo', 'E F azul', 'N S azul', '2', 'N O rojo', 'E S azul', '3', 'N S azul', 'E F rojo', 'F O rojo']

Cada camino debiese ser así: Camino(['E', 'N'], "verde")
```

Con esto puedo obtener la información guardada dentro del archivo y creo una lista con dicha información, ahora necesito guardar partes de esta información por separado, por cada camino, pero no se como puedo iterar para poder guardar el camino correspondiente de cada una.

Los caminos de las baldosas están dadas por coordenadas geográfica (Norte `n`, Sur `S`, Este `E` y Oeste `O`)

El formato del texto dentro del archivo baldosas.txt es el siguiente:

- La primera línea es un número entero N, correspondiente al número de baldosas que serán creadas.
- En las líneas que siguen, recibirás la información de las N baldosas. Para cada una de ellas, la primera línea será un segundo número entero M, indicando el número de caminos pertenecientes a esa baldosa.

El input seria este:

```
4
2
N O azul
E S azul
3
F O rojo
E F azul
N S azul
2
N O rojo
E S azul
3
N S azul
E F rojo
F O rojo
```

Aquí se visualiza:

- La primera baldosa, la cual tiene dos caminos: el camino rojo que va de norte (N) a oeste (O) y el azul que va de este (E) a sur (S).

Y tengo que crear una lista con los caminos, respecto a la información que sacamos del archivo.

Comment: si has intentado algo, pon el código! así sabremos que te interesa aprender y con mucho gusto te ayudaremos!

Comment: También agrega el `.txt` pues no sabemos nada de este.

Comment: se agradece la explicación de tu txt, pero siempre queda más claro con un ejemplo, asi sea uno simple y pequeño. Un ejemplo de datos de entrada y de salida

Comment: si hablas de ubicación, de acuerdo a que es dada esa ubicación??

Comment: la ubicación por default es (-1,-1)

Comment: eso se entiende, pero para lo demás?? cuales son las dimensiones del espacio?, a tu pregunta le falta mas detalles :c

Comment: dimensiones de que espacio?? en verdad esa es toda la información que tengo por eso me ha costado tanto hacer el ejercicio, esto seria como la explicación del output Luego se ve el resultado de imprimir y, posteriormente, visualizar la primera baldosa, la cual tiene dos caminos: el camino rojo que va de norte (N) a oeste (O) y el azul que va de este (E) a sur (S), y ubicación (-1, -1) por defecto.

Comment: eso era lo que faltaba, no se entendia lo de `N`,`O`, etc. añade eso a tu pregunta, así queda más explicada

Comment: Ahí si jajaja, gracias

Comment: ok, entonces esta información recibida, la quieres guardar en un txt??

Comment: en una lista, o eso entendí por el enunciado

Comment: Mmm... es un poco difícil trabajar si no sabes muy bien lo que se pide. Lo mejor sería usar un ciclo `for` para pedir los datos según el numero de caminos que se haya ingresado y estos datos almacenarlos en una lista

Comment: eso intente pero no pude, llevo muchas horas intentando y a lo maximo que llego es crear la lista, osea creo que claramente hice mal el ciclo

Comment: No entiendo nada

Comment: primero debería crear una lista de los caminos los caminos son en este formato: Camino(['E', 'O'], "rojo") y después crear la baldosa con la lista de caminos

Comment: @JosephGen trate de rescatar un poco la pregunta, creo que ahora tiene más sentido

Comment: que formato de lista me convendria mas para usar el ciclo for??? ['2', '\n']
['3', '\n']
['F', ' ', 'O', ' ', 'a', 'z', 'u', 'l', '\n']
['E', ' ', 'S', ' ', 'r', 'o', 'j', 'o', '\n']
['F', ' ', 'N', ' ', 'a', 'z', 'u', 'l', '\n']
['2', '\n']
['O', ' ', 'S', ' ', 'a', 'z', 'u', 'l', '\n']
['E', ' ', 'N', ' ', 'a', 'z', 'u', 'l', '\n'] este o ['2', '3', 'F O azul', 'E S rojo', 'F N azul', '2', 'O S azul', 'E N azul']

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres con formato

Comment: Tengo 2 codigos pero con uno imprimo todas esas listas, en cambio con el otro se imprime todo condensado en 1, pero ahí no se como separarla

Comment: Recomendación: agrega todo lo que has intentado con su respectiva explicación de por qué lo haces y cuál es el resultado que te da

Comment: Ahí se entiende un poco lo que hice? que debo reconocer que no es mucho

Comment: Si, pero falta un solo detalle, cuál es la entrada? Según lo que muestras la entrada es introducida por el usuario, pero tu estas leyendo el archivo y eso no tiene sentido

Comment: La entrada es la información que está dentro del archivo, no hay ningún otro input no se si es eso a lo que te refieres

Comment: ¿Qué significa la letra `F` en tu entrada?

Comment: @MauricioContreras F significa Fin

Comment: voy a hacer una respuesta, pero dime, ¿Qué es lo que tienes en tu archivo txt? y ¿Qué recibes del usuario?. Lo siento por hacer demasiadas preguntas, pero sigo sin entender muy bien (o soy pésimo leyendo >_<)

Comment: un ejemplo de lo que podría haber dentro de archivo txt seria lo siguiente: 4
2
N O azul
E S azul
3
F O rojo
E F azul
N S azul
2
N O rojo
E S azul
3
N S azul
E F rojo
F O rojo pero va en distintas líneas, es lo que en la pregunta sale el input seria

Comment: ok, ahora tengo todo más claro :D

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a los números que se tiene en el archivo podemos hacer algo fácil. Cada número representa el numero de caminos que se tendrá a continuación, y esto nos será útil si hacemos la lectura del archivo se hace con `readlines()` (que devuelve una lista).

Teniendo un `baldosas.txt` así:

```
2
N O rojo
E S azul
3
N O rojo
F S rojo
E F rojo
```

Al hacer un `readlines()` obtendremos algo como esto.

```
['2', 'N O rojo', 'E S azul', '3', 'N O rojo', 'F S rojo', 'E F rojo']
  ^     --esto--- y ---esto--|  ^  ---esto---  ---esto-- y --esto----
cantidad los proximos datos  |cantidad los proximos 3 datos
```

Es decir, para los primeros datos comenzaremos desde la posición `0` hasta la `2+1` (el 2 es dado por el archivo y el `+1` es por que no se toma el primer dato), luego podemos *truncar* la lista para que excluya lo que ya se tomo y entonces el proceso seria el mismo.

**ejemplo visual**

```
['2', 'N O rojo', 'E S azul', '3', 'N O rojo', 'F S rojo', 'E F rojo']
  ^
cogemos hasta la posicion 2+1 y excluimos eso

[3', 'N O rojo', 'F S rojo', 'E F rojo']
cogemos hasta la posicion 3+1 y excluimos eso

[] -> ya no hay caminos
```

Muy bien, y... ¿cómo hacemos esto?, podemos hacerlo con bucle ya que en cada iteración iremos cogiendo elementos y *truncando* la lista, yo elegí un ciclo `while`.

```py
def get_caminos():
    caminos = [] #contendra todos los caminos
    with open("baldosas.txt") as f: #abrimos el archivo
        #leemos y quitamos los saltos de linea
        baldosas = [dato.strip() for dato in f.readlines()] 

    #esto es para el while
    pos = 0 #indica dode estamos

    while pos<len(baldosas): #repetimos mientras no llegemos al final de la lista
        #obtemos el numero que indica el numero de caminos que tiene
        num_caminos = int(baldosas[0]) #convertimos a entero
        #escogemos solo los elementos que corresponde al camino
        camino = baldosas[1:num_caminos+1]
        caminos.append(camino)#agregamos a la lista caminos
        #"truncamos" la lista, tal que solo tenga los elementos que falta
        baldosas = baldosas[num_caminos+1:]
        pos = num_caminos #asiganmos la nueva posicion
    return caminos #retornamos la lista con todos los caminos
```

**probamos**

```py
caminos = get_caminos()
print(caminos)
```

**resultado**

```
[['N O rojo', 'E S azul'], ['N O rojo', 'F S rojo', 'E F rojo']]
```

El primer elemento (`['N O rojo', 'E S azul']`) indica el primer camino y el segundo (`['N O rojo', 'F S rojo', 'E F rojo']`) lo mismo.

Comment: En la parte de num_caminos = int(baldosas[0] no mostraria in ValueError

Comment: nop, por que?..

Comment: nop, se toma la posición `0` de la lista que contiene toda la información `['2', 'N O rojo', 'E S azul', '3', 'N O rojo', 'F S rojo', 'E F rojo']` en este caso la posición `0` es `2` y esto se utiliza para determinar la cantidad de datos que tomaremos

Comment: es que me aparece ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'E S rojo'

Comment: Verifica que tu txt sea igual al que utilizo yo, de lo contrario modifica tu pregunta añadiendo tal cual lo tienes (ctrl+c y ctrl+v)

Comment: Ahí edite con otro que tenía a mano, el formato de la lista es el mismo, por que el código debería funcionar para cualquier largo de txt verdad?

Comment: al momento de leerlo haz esto `baldosas = [dato.strip() for dato in f.readlines()][1:]`

Comment: En ese caso imprimer solo el primer camino de la lista ['N O azul', 'E S azul']

Comment: acabo de probarlo y a mi me funciona, verifica haber hecho todo lo que pongo en el codigo

Comment: tengo lo mismo, pero sigue sin funcionar, en donde lo estas probando, para ver a lo mejor es mi programa

Comment: puedes verlo y probarlo [aquí](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rnTqyAkJDFf1hwAyyNd7PYmAD3Ah_tX7?usp=sharing)

Comment: siii creo que el problema es de mi programa, otra pregunta como podría rescatar el numero de caminos, para que quede así en cada uno de los caminos? "Baldosa: Num. de Caminos =" + 3 +", Ubicacion = (-1, -1)"

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127395/discussion-between-christian-and-user237999).

Comment: creo que no puedo hablar por el chat

Comment: por que? dale click al enlace y luego buscas un boton que diga *join this room*

Comment: no tengo suficiente reputacion You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the faq.

Comment: pero tienes 31!, mira [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat)

Comment: me sale el mensaje todavía );

Comment: Y las baldosas dejarlas asi?? extremos = {L}, color = {C} ;
  Camino(['E', 'N'], "verde")

Comment: de donde sale `L` y `C`???

Comment: L seria N, S, E, O o F dependiendo del camino (las letras de cada camino) y C el color

Comment: intenta volver a entrar al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127395/discussion-between-christian-and-user237999)

Comment: ok, lo intentare, puedo verlo, pero no escribir, no se por que

Comment: Mmm... bueno, para hacer lo que pides solo tendrías que trabajar con la variable `camino`(antes de hacer el append)

Comment: Holaa, todavia no lo puedo lograr, me podrias ayudar?

Comment: puedes entrar al chat???

Comment: de entrar puedo, pero no me deja comentar nada

Comment: debes de buscar un boton que diga *join this room*

Comment: en que parte deberia estar?

Comment: si estas en una pc, deberia de aparecer casi al final de la página, busca varios botones de color naranja y si estas en un dispositivo móvil debería de estar en la parte lateral derecha

Comment: en el final me sale esto: You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the faq. (estoy en pc)

Comment: Bueno, espera un momento hablo con un moderador

Comment: has iniciado sesión??

Comment: Ahora si puedo hablar por el chat